# Argumentative son is reprimanded during conversation assertively to "stay shut". Is the usage of "stay shut" correct?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

In order to quieten the son's inappropriate argument which was getting out of control, the mother commands the son to "stay shut". Is the term "stay shut" correct or incorrect?

Comment: Please add a linked reference to where you found this example. If this suggested usage (for "Be quiet!") has no pedigree, it should not be posted here. And in any case, clear evidence of research needs to be provided, CodeN.

Comment: “Stay shut up” is probably the form you are looking for!

Comment: It's informal usage.  Would be understood (and regarded as "normal") in most of the US.

Comment: In UK we would say "[shut it](https://www.lexico.com/definition/shut_it)".

Comment: People say all sorts of things in arguments and in families. And they tend to worry less about grammar than getting their point across. It's obvious what the object of "shut" is. If you're looking for the usual ways to say be quiet, that's a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you heard this in conversation somewhere.  It sounds like the speaker is not a native speaker of English, or maybe it's a regional expression somewhere.